# Удалить минимальный ключ из массива. (PHP)

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как удалить минимальный ключ с его значением из массива?
Ключ в массиве это разные числа **time()**, нужно найти и удалить самый старый.

```
Array
    (
        [1598557734] => 23
        [1598557741] => 11
        [1598557634] => 23
        [1598557811] => 43
    )
```

Comment: Отсортируйте [массив](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php) по ключу и удалите первый элемент из массива получив [первый ключ](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-first) по списку оператором array_key_first().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unset($array[min(array_keys($array))])
```

Пояснение:

- `array_keys($array)` - создаёт массив, состоящий из ключей исходного
  массива
- `min()` - возвращает минимальное число в массиве (оно и
  есть минимальный ключ)
- `unset()` - удаляет элемент